# If NASA could send a camera into a black hole, could we then see what's inside the black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, reference-frames, event-horizon, observers

Inspired by [Stephen Hawking](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.5761) I recently tripped upon an idea of what is really inside a black hole.

I thought if NASA (or any other space agency) could send a super protected camera into a black hole, then we could see what's inside black hole.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Short answer: no. For more information, take a look at e.g. [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98552/16660), its answers and the links therein.

Comment: Pretty much all you have here is the McGuffin for a SciFi story.  "super protected" would have to be rather more technologically advanced than even a General Products spaceship hull.

Comment: Plus for us - stationary observers - camera wouldn't actually fall into black hole in finite time.

Comment: @JarosławKomar Yeah, but our "super protected" camera will have been dropped into a local wormhole, thus bypassing the event horizon :-)

Comment: Also, in order for the camera to capture any image inside the black hole, light needs to be able to come to the camera from somewhere below the camera. But photons can not go back up to where the camera is because they are subject to a higher gravitational force than the camera. For the same reason the camera cannot film up because it is falling faster than the photons chasing it. It can't see sideways either, because photos won't be able to travel sideways. Effectively, the camera sees nothing but darkness.

Comment: @luis: if the camera is falling freely this isn't true. A freely falling observer sees the event horizon receding before them and they never cross it.

Comment: @John_Rennie Yes, you're right about that, but I believe this depends whether it is a massive black hole or smaller black hole. I was under the impression that in a massive black holes, the observer will not experience the event horizon receding.  Isn't that true?

Comment: Not sure of the reason for the downvotes... it seems like a perfectly good question even if the answer is negative.

Answer (score 3):

No, not even light can escape a black hole, therefore radio will be unable to broadcast signals back to Earth. (Radio is a form of light)

Comment: You have ignored the ejection jets and a lot of other black-hole theory.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft But none of that matters. Jets and *any* other observables are produced outside the event horizon, by definition.

Comment: @ChrisWhite True enough,  but I'm still in "SciFi story only" mode, in which case, as a wisacre friend of mine once said, "... because Science Magic"

Answer (score -2):

No. It would not be possible. Things get very hot around the edge of a black hole. There is no technology that exists or is likely to exist that could protect a camera. The fact that EM radiation is in fact light and the strength of gravity...lalala. No. It's just not possible.